# Include live figures Matplotlib on PDF

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf, latex

I wanted to know if it is possible to include interactive figures in PDF.

For example, I wanted to generate figures with Matplotlib, create a PDF with Latex and be able to zoom or pan inside the figures on the PDF. (The same behavior that we have for example when we plot with Matplotlib)

Maybe there is a format that can handle this feature ?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot put interactive figures in PDFs without losing their "interactive" property.

The way interactive plots are usually shared is using Ipython notebooks, which can either work in [`jupyter lab`](https://jupyter.org/) for offline access or in `google colab` or other similar online platforms from your browser without downloading jupyter, you can also put LaTeX in the notebooks as well as text, And you can export them to PDF but lose the interactivity.

For interactive plots in jupyter you should see the [ipympl](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/) library to imbed them in your notebook.

There's also PowerBi that is more friendly for non-programmers to preview the documents, but it's less mature than ipython.

Comment: Yes and no. That answer is technically not correct. There was a time in which you could insert interactive figures in PDF which essentially would require Flash. PDF supported Rich Media Annotations in which interactive graphs and such could be placed into PDF. But with the demise of Flash, it is no longer supported.